# Google table chart not loading toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, charts

I have used bootstrap toggle for on off button.

If I used this out of the google table chart it is working fine. But it was showing the simple checkbox inside the google table.

```html
<html>
<head> 
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Alerts</title>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.0/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.0/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>

</head>


    <script type='text/javascript'>

      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['table'], "callback": drawTable});

      function drawTable() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Report');
        data.addColumn('string', '');
        data.setColumnProperty(1, {allowHtml: true});
        data.addRows([
        ["aaaa",'<input  id ="toggle" class="toggle" data-toggle="toggle" type = "checkbox"   data-width="100" />'],
 ["dddd",'<input id="toogle" data-toggle="toggle" type="checkbox" data-width="100"/>'],

        ]);
            options = {showRowNumber: true,'height':250,}
      var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('chart_div1'));
      table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true, allowHtml: true, page:'enable', pageSize:8});
$('.toggle').bootstrapToggle('toggle');
      };
    </script>

 <body>

<div class = "chart_div1" id = "chart_div1"></div>

<input id="toogle" data-toggle="toggle" type="checkbox" data-width="100"/>


</body>
</html>
```

Please give me a solution for this,

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove line 16

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```